Extending a type in GraphQL / Apollo Federation
What
I'm trying to extend another type using GraphQL federation under using the following syntax:
[Key("id")]
[Extends]
public class Parent
{
    [ID]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public List<Child> Children()
    {
        return new List<Child>
        {
            new Child("1", "Child 1"),
            new Child("2", "Child 2")
        };
    }
}

And the following registration code:
   .AddTypeExtension<Parent>()

Is what I'm trying to do possible? If so, what am I doing wrong?
Repro
I have created a minimal reproduction of my scenario here:
https://github.com/rquackenbush/apollo-federation-repro
